# Loop image to move up and down with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have a small script that moves an apple up and down however it is not working and I am not sure why. Currently the apple moves down then it moves up, then does nothing.

Here is my code, not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
<section class="apple">
    <img class="applePic" src="apple.png" alt="">
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loopDown(){
        $(".applePic").animate({
            marginTop : 10
            },
            500, function() {
            loopUp();
        });
    }

    function loopUp(){
        $(".applePic").animate({
            marginTop : 0
            },
            500, function() {
            loopDown();
        });
    }

    loopDown();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be two reasons.

1. You did not attach the jQuery library to your page.
2. You forgot to place JavaScript code within body in your HTML page.

**Note**: place your script code at bottom of html tags just before ending body (`</body>`) within `<script> .... </script>`

Here it is - this **will not work** as no jQuery library is added.

```html
<section class="apple">
    <img class="applePic" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/54/Red_Apple.png" alt="">
</section> 
<script>
 function loopDown(){
        $(".applePic").animate({
            marginTop : 10
            },
            500, function() {
            loopUp();
        });
    }

    function loopUp(){
        $(".applePic").animate({
            marginTop : 0
            },
            500, function() {
            loopDown();
        });
    }

 loopDown();
 
</script>
```

**With JQuery Library :**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="apple">
    <img class="applePic" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/54/Red_Apple.png" alt="">
</section>

<script>
 function loopDown(){
        $(".applePic").animate({
            marginTop : 10
            },
            500, function() {
            loopUp();
        });
    }

    function loopUp(){
        $(".applePic").animate({
            marginTop : 0
            },
            500, function() {
            loopDown();
        });
    }

 loopDown();
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your forgot to add the Jquery Document ready function.

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    loopDown();
});

function loopDown(){
    $(".applePic").animate({
        marginTop : 10
      },
        500, function() {
          loopUp();
     });
}

function loopUp(){
     $(".applePic").animate({
        marginTop : 0
      },
        500, function() {
          loopDown();
      });
}
```

[Working example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IndieRok/67ys7v5k/)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly disrecommend to use described approach. Using jQuery.fn.animate, especially in loop and especially for animation of properties like `marginTop` (which affect whole document) is going to be performance-consuming and jerky.

Css animation is here your best option - and to animate transform translateY (up/down).

```
.applePic{
animation: updown 500ms infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes updown { 
0%{
transform: translate(0px,10px);
}
100%{
transform: translate(0px,0px);
}
}
```

...of course, with proper vendor prefixes which applies to `animation`, `@keyframes` and `transform`